# How to truncate the lines to specific length in a file which occurs between specific patterns?

Tags: awk, cut

I have a file in which I have to truncate only the lines which comes between pattern @TEST and enabled="true">. When there is a match, the string between @TEST and enabled="true"> should be only 50 characters. All other lines should be left intact.

Example 1:

```
@TEST-TC_234 @TEST My name is Elli,I like to Travel, my hobbies are reading books,cooking,listening to music.I have a dog and the dog is black in colour  enabled="true">
```

I have to change above line as shown below.

```
@TEST-TC_234 @TEST My name is Elli,I like to Travel, my hobbies are r enabled="true">
```

Also I have few sentences containing special characters which needs to be truncated as above

Example

```
@TEST 05030508227_${mode} @TEST 2 Framed ABCSubData (ABCupdateLoc) with abcdcsmelSubscriptionInfo parameter  populated by tub and ABC DOS data, when ABCDN DOS &amp; xyzabcdeDOS both use  E.164 rule where the Restriction is &apos;4-restrict via ABC DOS&apos;" enabled="true">
```

I have to change above line as shown below.

Comment: some proof of your failed attempts?

Comment: @karakfa I have no idea how to achieve it. so any suggestion on this will be highly appreciated

Comment: At least provide the pseudo-code you have in mind.

Comment: $ grep -oP '(?<=@TEST ).*(?=\" enabled=\"true\")' inputfile | cut -c1-50 >> outputfile. I tried this but it is printing only the truncated line to the outputfile. But I want to update the same input file without changing any other content of the file.

Comment: It's the most, wonderful tiiiime of the yeeeear! [An open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{if(match($0,/@TEST .*enabled="true">$/))
          {bo=length("@TEST");
           eo=length("enabled=\"true\">"); 
           len=(RLENGTH-bo-eo)>50?50:RLENGTH-bo-eo; 
           print substr($0,0,RSTART+bo+len) substr($0,length($0)-eo)}
       else print}' file
```

split the line for begin/end pattern if there is match; truncate the mid section and put them back together.  If there is no match print unmodified lines.

For the updated example, the above script yields

```
@TEST 05030508227_${mode} @TEST 2 Framed ABCSubData (ABCupdateLoc) with abcdcsme enabled="true">
```

Comment: thank you for the rescue, It is truncating the sentence but It has removed the sign > from the end of the sentence after the word "true". example:- My name is Elli,I like to Travel, my hobbies are r enabled="true". How to correct it. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Perhaps it is a one off error, add 1 to the last substr last arg.

Comment: You mean like this print substr($0,0,RSTART+bo+len) substr($0,length($0)-eo,eo+1)} ? How about writing it like this print substr($0,0,RSTART+bo+len) substr($0,length($0)-eo)} Will it create any issue in the logic you applied here for length calculation?

Comment: This command worked for all the files except one which has few sentences like this : @TEST 05030508227_${mode} TEST 2 Framed ABCSubData (ABCupdateLoc) with abcdcsmelSubscriptionInfo parameter  populated by sub and ABC COS data, when ABCDN COS &amp; xyzabcdeCOS both use  E.164 rule where the Restriction is &apos;4-restrict via ABC COS&apos;" enabled="true">. Can you tell me why above command is not working for this type of sentences. how can I solve it ?

Comment: do you have a line break? It expects the content to be on the same line.  It can be modified to handle it as well.  please amend the original Q with this data.

Comment: No it does not have any line break, I have modified the question

Comment: It has removed ${mode} from the output. How to avoid it ?

Comment: It's copy/paste error, `bash` evaluated `$..`, I now copied correctly.  What is the issue you have?

Comment: Its not working for me when the sentence have special characters _,$,{},(),&,;,/,- and .

Comment: That shouldn't matter for `awk` script.  I think it fails in other parts of your pipeline...